# Can I use dust.js as a preprocessor for css and js? Is there any side effects of doing so?

Tags: dust.js

since we are using dust.js to write templates, we have extended it to write css and js. For css and js our requirement is minimal. We just want to keep the location of assets in a variable which is passed to css and js during preprocessor stage. I tested it in all possible scenarios and it worked. Is there any side effect of using it this way?

I am not using less or sass because our requirement is very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, dust.js is just a text parser-- it doesn't care what sort of text you throw at it.

You should be careful to [configure whitespace suppression](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-Controlling_whitespace_suppression) if you are using dust to parse a whitespace-sensitive language like Javascript (newlines are very important for meaning in Javascript due to one-line comments and automatic semicolon insertion). For CSS, whitespace has no effect.

Comment: since @ is used for referring to dust helpers, usage of at-rulesets (like @media, etc) will throw error.

Comment: @GolakSarangi that is incorrect. The Dust parser is very strict when looking for tags that it considers Dust-like, and something like a media query will not trigger it-- only curly-brace tags like {@helper} will be interpreted by the parser.

Comment: This will fail while compiling
`@media only screen and (max-width : 770px) {
    #someid {float: none;}
}`

But replacing the id with a class selector works
`@media only screen and (max-width : 770px) {
    .someid {float: none;}
}`

Comment: It fails because of no space between `{` and `float`, not anything to do with the media query. Keep your CSS properly indented and Dust will have no problem.